# Org-export: LaTeX--->PDF with multipage #+INCLUDE

Tags: org-export, latex, lilypond

I'm new to the `#+INCLUDE` command, and am using it to assemble a book of sheet music.

At the top of the file I've placed a `#+LaTeX_HEADER` to use the `\fancyhdr` package for footers for all the pages in the book. After a few pages of text introduction, I insert sheet music:

```
#+INCLUDE: "/home/me/music.ly" src lilypond :file output.eps
```

This does kind of work, but there are about 4 pages of outputted sheet music, and only the first ends up in the exported PDF. Additionally, there is this collision between the sheet music and the footer:

[image]

I wonder, on the one hand, if it's possible to get `#+INCLUDE` to include all of the pages of sheet music within the bounds of the margins of the page---and on the other hand if doing this with `Org` might be less sensible than directly using `LaTeX` or `Lilypond-book`. I'm struggling to get my head around it all, and would appreciate any voices of experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the lilypond file is compiled into a picture that is then included in the latex file by the latex macro `\includegraphics` which is not supposed to handle multi-page files.

Since you apparently don't want to edit your lilypond files from the org file (you would use src blocks rather than `#+INCLUDE:`), I would suggest that you:

- convert them to pdf outside of org (`lilypond music.ly` in a command
  line shell should create file `music.pdf` for example),
- include them through `\includepdf` from the `pdfpages` latex package.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
#+TITLE: test include lilypond through includepdf
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{pdfpages}

* intro

bla bla

now the music !

\includepdf[pages=-]{music.pdf}
```

This turns out to be more of a latex answer than an org one.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the solution I've ended up using. I stumbled across a good blogpost on the subject at http://lilypondblog.org/2013/07/creating-songbooks-with-lilypond-and-latex/, which recommended your same solution. The only other thing I had to do was use the \paper environment in Lilypond to get the pdf margins to match the margins I'd set in LaTeX (for header and footer issues). Thank you!